# CSS Naming Best Practice in MVC Layouts

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a CSS naming convention in an MVC Project with Layouts.

The use of Layouts creates the need to be very careful when it comes to choose the name of a class because it can be override by one declared in the Layout CSS file.

One rule I use is to have only element classes for style and element ID's for jQuery use.

Let say I have a layout like this:

```
<div class="lyb-ctn">
    <div class="lyb-wrp">

        @RenderBody()

        <div class="lyb-ctn-rgt">
            <div class="lyb-ctn-subscribe">
                <p class="lyb-ctn-subscribe-title">Subscribe</p>
                <input placeholder="Email" /><input type="button" />
            </div>
            <div class="lyb-ctn-categories">
                <p class="lyb-ctn-categories-title">Categories</p>
                <div class="lyb-ctn-categories-ctn-list">
                    <div class="category">
                        <p>Cars</p>
                        <p>Boats</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One option would be:

```
.lyb-ctn {
    position:fixed;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.lyb-wrp {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ffd800;
}

.lyb-ctn-rgt {
    float: right;
    width: 235px;
    border: solid 1px #ff6a00;
}

.lyb-ctn-subscribe {
    width: 100%;
}

.lyb-ctn-subscribe-title {
    color: #80bd01;
}

.lyb-ctn-categories {
    width: 100%;
}

.lyb-ctn-categories-title {
    color: #80bd01;
}
```

I also build an other option but this one, I think, is dangerous because if it happens to exist a ".rgt-ctn" in the parent layout, it can override this one:

```
.lyb-ctn {
    position:fixed;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.lyb-ctn .wrp {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ffd800;
}

.lyb-ctn .wrp .rgt-ctn {
    float: right;
    width: 235px;
    border: solid 1px #ff6a00;
}

.lyb-ctn .wrp .rgt-ctn .subscribe-ctn {
    width: 100%;
}

.lyb-ctn .wrp .rgt-ctn .subscribe-ctn .title {
    color: #80bd01;
}
```

Here is another one that seems clean but we can't see the hierarquy of the DOM when we look at it, and I think it maybe more difficult to find an element to edit:

```
.lyb-ctn {
    position:fixed;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.lyb-wrp {
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ffd800;
}

.ctn-side-options {
    float: right;
    width: 235px;
}

.ctn-subscribe,
.ctn-categories,
.ctn-tags {
    width: 100%;
}

.ctn-subscribe .title, 
.ctn-categories .title,
.ctn-tags .title {
    color: #80bd01;
    padding: 25px 0 10px 5px;
}

.ctn-categories .ctn-list, 
.ctn-tags .ctn-list {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or is there a better approach?

Comment: It partly depends if you are going to have other `.wrp` etc elements in your site. Either way, I tend to go with option2 so your html doesn't get stuffed up with long CSS class names - the point of them is that they _cascade_ after all

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But for example ".title" is very common, this may cary the risk of overriding...no?

Comment: `.lyb-ctn .wrp .rgt-ctn .subscribe-ctn .title` is very specific so I think it is unlikely to  get overridden. The point of a "class" is that it defines the styles for a class (i.e. set of _similar_) elements. So you may have a global `.title {font-weight:bold;}` making all titles bold, but only your `.subscribe-ctn .title` is  green. Taking care over class naming conventions is good, but you also need to be careful of how you then use them

Comment: I made a small test to be sure that .title in the layoutblog.css is not overided by a .title in the layout.css file and thats correct. It assumes the closest one.

Comment: I think you're putting way too much concern on this.  styles are intended to be cascaded, so whenever you create a style or an element you need to think about how existing styles affect or are affected.  Each page is an aggregation of all styles, and you need to view it as such... not as individual pieces that stand on their own.

Comment: Hi @ErikFunkenbusch, thanks for your help. The issue here is that I have worked on templates based in an aggregation of all styles and it was very dificult to keep the pieces all together when I started to move elements from place to place, because the styles just started to break.

Comment: @Patrick - Perhaps what you really mean is, is there a *methodology* for creating styles in such a way that are less brittle.  Much like we have methodologies for software development to make change in software less brittle, the same is true of other technologies like CSS.  If you just haphazardly create rules and use them, then it becomes difficult to change them without knowing what will break.  This is not so much an issue with naming (although I can see how naming would help) as it is with structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLDR : Get organised.

Firstly, I strongly recommend you read up on:

OOCSS - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/

SMACSS - https://smacss.com/

and

BEM - http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

Putting some effort into gaining an understanding of a modular approach to CSS at the start of a project will pay huge dividends as the project becomes larger. Having a strong naming convention will make life a lot easier if you are working on a project with two or more developers.

Next, if you aren't already doing so, it it well worth transitioning to a CSS pre-processor such as SASS - http://sass-lang.com/, LESS - http://lesscss.org/ or STYLUS - http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/

Using a pre-processor helps organisation because you can break your stylesheets into as many files as you want, then import them all into one at compile time to follow performance best practice. (See also - http://thesassway.com/advanced/modular-css-naming-conventions)

You mention you have a rule of only using classes as CSS hooks and IDs as JS hooks - this is a good start, however I recommend moving away from using IDs and move towards a js- prefixed class. In this way your JS also becomes re-usable.

The next thing to look at is creating a pattern library - a great example of this is Mailchimp's example - http://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns

So much for general guidance - how is all this relevant to:

*"I need to create a CSS naming convention in an MVC Project with Layouts.
  The use of Layouts creates the need to be very careful when it comes to choose the name of a class because it can be override by one declared in the Layout CSS file."*

You will see all of the above guides all aim towards organising your CSS (and JS) in to chunks of reusable code. The key to this is planning, and having a canonical reference for each chunk you are going to use - hence the pattern library.

In your example you might like to create a guide for each of your layouts - how is each layout used and how does / should it affect descendant content?

Where you want layouts to pro-actively influence their descendant content you will want to scope them. So wrap them in a class which can act as a namespace. I.e.

```
<div class="layout-one">[ALL DESCENDANT CONTENT HERE]</div>
.layout-one p {
    color: green;
}

<div class="layout-two">[ALL DESCENDANT CONTENT HERE]</div>
.layout-two p {
    color: red;
}
```

However, I take it your concern is more that your layouts are going to re-actively influence descendant content in a way which breaks your design. So scope any styles which relate only to the layouts but not the descendants more tightly.

Rather than:
    .layout-one p {}
as above, go for
    .layout-one__p {}, .layout-one__h4 {}

As you can see this BEM inspired naming convention makes it immediately clear the the style in question is directly part of the layout. We would not expect to see this class being used outside of the layout HTML, so we can write styles without any concerns about them affecting descendant content.

Or, we can write styles within a layout's namespace and be sure that our styles will be affected as we want.

Comment: Thanks Simon for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first and second layout are totally different story. For instance: in the second layout, (I Believe) class `.lyb-ctn .wrp` means they will also pass rules havent been took place from `.lyb-ctn` to `.wrp`.

```
.lyb-ctn .wrp{
    position:fixed;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding-top: 50px;
```

> following is the code from .wrp which will override only **part of** the
>   .lyb-ctn class

```
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ffd800;

}
```

Well, they might appear to be the same in browser for now. But with more and more style involves in, it's very easy to get into unexpected result.

I think the third one makes more scenes in this case.

Answer (score 1):

first I'd use camelcase naming

second use as much classes and as little ids in css as possible as this enables code reuse, also it's better to have

`.w100 { width: 100%; } .black { color: black; }`

than

`.something { width: 100%; color: black; }`

or even worse

`#something { width: 100%; color: black; }`

Comment: Thanks Prozi for your tips. Sometimes I get to the conclusion that your answer is the best way to go. But there are situations where we need a lot of information for styçling an element and we just can't put 10 or 15 classes, don't you think?

Comment: sure also use id's that's what they're for but instead of just classes and id's you can use css3 selectors like table.dupa > tr:first-child > td:not(:empty) { color: red; }

Comment: and also validate with w3c css3 online validation